# Jquery AutoComplete results on Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Is it possible to show the results of Jquery autocomplete on a partial view ?
This is how i am showing now, i was hoping to show the results on a partial view, so that i have more control to style the results.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
            .each(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url"),
                    minLength: 2,
                    messages: {
                        noResults: "",
                        results: function () { }
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        return false;
                    },
                });
            }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                  )
.append('<table><tr><td valign="top"><img style="width:30px;height:30px;" src="' + "/Images/Image.jpg" + '" /></td><td valign="top">' + item.FirstName + item.LastName + '</td></tr></table>')
                                       .appendTo(ul);
            }
    });
```

Also, when the user select an item from the results, i would like to call a controller action by passing the id, Could anyone provide a code sample for this ?

I am using Asp.net MVC 4,

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can't render a partial view using only jQuery. You can, however, call a method (action) that will render the partial view for you and add it to the page using jQuery/AJAX.
While the user selects an item or hover an item, just use a jquery function and using ajax pass the id to server and return a Partail View.

```
$.get( '<%= Url.Action("details","user", new { id = Model.ID } %>', function(data) {
    $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(data);
});
```

Razor

```
$.get( '@Url.Action("details","user", new { id = Model.ID } )', function(data) {
    $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(data);
});
```

where the user controller has an action named details that does:

```
public ActionResult Details( int id )
{
    var model = ...get user from db using id...

    return Partial( "UserDetails", model );
}
```

Refer these links, you will get a better idea.
[Render Partial View Using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc),
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41828/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-NET-MVC,
[ASP.NET MVC AJAX with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578443/asp-net-mvc-ajax-with-jquery)

Thanks. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks ! I guess i was not clear about my first question. I was trying to format the autocomplete results using a partial view, but i guess my only option is to use ._renderItem ?